# trouble finding if the range is empty to allow me to move on with the code. JAVA

Tags: java

```
    int[] intRange1 = {};
    intNum = getValidInt(sIn, "Please enter a whole number: ",
            "Invalid response. Only whole numbers are acceptable.", intRange1);
    System.out.println("The whole number your entered was: " + intNum);
    System.out.println("Now we will test your whole number in a math equation...");
    System.out.printf("Adding 10 to your whole number would be: 10 + %d = %d.\n\n", intNum, (intNum + 10));

    // Get an integer within a range from the user
    int[] intRange2 = { 10, 50 };
    intNum = getValidInt(sIn, "Please enter a whole number between 10 and 50: ",
            "Invalid response. Only whole numbers between 10 and 50 are acceptable.", intRange2);
    System.out.println("The whole number your entered was: " + intNum);
    System.out.println("Now we will test your whole number in a math equation...");
    System.out.printf("Adding 10 to your whole number would be: 10 + %d = %d.\n\n", intNum, (intNum + 10));
}
/*
 * making the method I can get it to validate the first part but I can not get
 * it to do the part with the range
 */

public static int getValidInt(Scanner sIn, String question, String warning, int[] range) {
    boolean valid = false;
    int validNumber = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a whole number: ");
        String number = sIn.nextLine();

        try {
            validNumber = Integer.parseInt(number);
            valid = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            System.out.println("Invalid response. Only whole numbers are acceptable.");
            valid = false;

        } // end of try/catch block
    } while (!valid);// end of do while
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, you are not able to find out if user has input blank space?

Comment: rather than range, why not just pass the two integers, minVal and maxVal, then valid = (validNumber>=minVal && validNumber<=maxVal)

Comment: also it would be a nice touch to specify "between "+minVal +" and "+maxVal in the prompt or to use the parameter question that you passed in.

Comment: @gdm Hi there. Can you please use capitalization in your post... it's really important to try to make it readable. Also please go back and look at your code in your post. You need to make sure all of it is in {} code format. Also Please add some sentence or 2 before you paste your first block of code. This will make it sooooo much easier to answer. All in all, it needs to be more easy to understand but I have voted to leave this question open so you can work with SO on this.

Comment: @Chrips there is an edit in that reformats and just needs one more approval.

Comment: @JeremyKahan I sure would like if the user goes ahead and continues working on it though. Theres no explanation really... just code

Comment: @Chrips I hope so too.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do

```java
    int v = SIn.nextInt();
```

and then catch the exception if it's not an integer.  Try the following:

```java
    Scanner sIn = new Scanner(System.in);


    int r = getValue(sIn, 10, 40);

    System.out.println("You entered " + r);

    static int getValue(Scanner sIn, int low, int high) {
      String msg = "Please enter a number between %d and %d%n";
      while (true) {
         System.out.printf(msg, low, high);
         System.out.print("Enter: ");
         try {
            int v = sIn.nextInt();
            if (v >= low && v <= high) {
               sIn.nextLine();//clear input buffer
               return v;
            }
            System.out.printf("Number out of range (%d).", v);
         }
         catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.printf("Illegal input type (%s)%n", sIn.nextLine());
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: The OP wants to check if the input number is >= a min val and <= a max val. They're using a range for that. I think it might be simpler to specify them as ints and check >=min && <=max

Comment: This was just an example of using nextInt() instead of trying parse a string.

Comment: Oh, okay. It just sounded to me like the range was what was difficult ("but I can not get it to do the part with the range"). I understand that nextInt is an improvement here, just not sure it's a complete answer (though I'm sure you could extend it to one)

Comment: Nice job adding that feature. Upvoting.